# How can solve the SIGABRT in UITableView when calling the "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths"

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm the beginner of IOS development. I build an UITableView with data,
but at the last row, it's not a data row, called "load more item".(this display name is not good. i will change it later, may be after i fixed this problem)

the "load more item" include 2 functions:
When selected the last row, this table will auto append 4 rows.
When selected again, these new 4 rows will be deleted. and agains.

But when I selected "load more item" at second time, it appear the "Program received signal: 'SIGABRT' ".

```
... ...
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
 // Error here, SIGABRT, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
... ...
```

I built this xcode project in Xcode 4.2.1, ios5 SDK ,without ARC, but there is a problem during the runtime . Here given in the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [posts count] + 1;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
static NSString *postCellId = @"postCell";
static NSString *moreCellId = @"moreCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSUInteger count = [posts count];

if (row == count) {
    NSLog(@"%@ -  indexPath : %d",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [indexPath row]);
    
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:moreCellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                 reuseIdentifier:moreCellId] autorelease];
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more items...";
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    
    
} else {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                 reuseIdentifier:postCellId] autorelease];
    }

    Post *currentPost = [posts objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [currentPost postTitle];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [currentPost postDescr];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
}

return cell;}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
               didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSUInteger count = [posts count];

if (row == count) {
    
    if(SIMPLE_FLAG_INT==0){
        NSArray *newPosts = [feed detailPosts];
        NSUInteger newCount = [newPosts count];
        
        if (newCount) {
            
            [self.posts addObjectsFromArray:newPosts];
            [newPosts release];
            
            NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSUInteger item = count; item < count + newCount; item++) {
                
                [insertIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:item 
                                                               inSection:0]];
            }

                
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];  
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths 
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
            
            SIMPLE_FLAG_INT = 1;
            
            
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
            
           
        }
    }else{
        SIMPLE_FLAG_INT = 0;

        NSLog(@" ==> %d num of row in section 0 ",[self tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:0]);


        NSMutableArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        [deleteIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6   inSection:0]];
        [deleteIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5   inSection:0]];
        [deleteIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4   inSection:0]];    
        [deleteIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3   inSection:0]];
        
        
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        // Error here, SIGABRT, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];  
        [self.tableView endUpdates];               
    }
    
    NSIndexPath *selected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSLog(@"%@ - indexPathForSelectedRow(selected row): %d",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [selected row]);
    if (selected) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected animated:YES];
    }
    
} else {

    PostViewController *postController = [[PostViewController alloc] 
                                          initWithNibName:@"PostView" 
                                          bundle:nil];
    postController.post = [posts objectAtIndex:row];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:postController 
                                           animated:YES];
    [postController release];
} }
```

Here is the console output:

> 2012-03-28 02:20:22.059 Feeder[4577:bf03] tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
>
> 2012-03-28 02:20:22.064 Feeder[4577:bf03] tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: - indexPathForSelectedRow(selected row): 7
>
> 2012-03-28 02:20:23.600 Feeder[4577:bf03] tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
>
> 2012-03-28 02:20:23.601 Feeder[4577:bf03]  ==> 8 num of row in section 0
>
> Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>
> 2012-03-28 02:21:05.756 Feeder[4577:bf03] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
>
> 2012-03-28 02:21:05.758 Feeder[4577:bf03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 4 deleted).'
>
> *** Call stack at first throw:
>
> (
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fd75a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0112b313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f8fef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
>
> 3   Foundation                          0x008193bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
>
> 4   UIKit                               0x00094e8b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8420
>
> 5   UIKit                               0x000841e8 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 42
>
> 6   Feeder                              0x0000356b -[FeedViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 1371
>
> 7   UIKit                               0x0008db68 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
>
> 8   UIKit                               0x00083b05 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
>
> 9   Foundation                          0x0079d79e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
>
> 10  CoreFoundation                      0x00fb88c3 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 19
>
> 11  CoreFoundation                      0x00fb9e74 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
>
> 12  CoreFoundation                      0x00f162c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
>
> 13  CoreFoundation                      0x00f15840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>
> 14  CoreFoundation                      0x00f15761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
>
> 15  GraphicsServices                    0x00cd71c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
>
> 16  GraphicsServices                    0x00cd7289 GSEventRun + 115
>
> 17  UIKit                               0x00024c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>
> 18  Feeder                              0x000027cd main + 125
>
> 19  Feeder                              0x00002745 start + 53
>
> 20  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1

Screen Capture:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to you add "Load more items..." into your posts array?

I'm saying that because it seems to me that the problem is the **return [posts count] + 1** in the method **numberOfRowsInSection**.

I guess the **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths** is trying to check the number of records in your array after the deleting and it is not matching because the "plus one" in the method **numberOfRowsInSection**.

Comment: i have already corrected the numbeOfRowsInSection method.
"return [posts count]"

But seems not work.
"SIGABRT" program still Occured.